# Lambda and file writing

Tags: python-2.7

Trying to figure out why I can't get Lambda to work with writing a file.
Here is my code:

```
list = (i*2 for i in range(10))
file = open("text.txt", "a")
lambda i: (file.write(str(i) + "\n")), list
```

and I don't even get to close the file before I get following error message:

```
(<function <lambda> at 0x021E1B30>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x021EC418>)
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? That's not an error message, it's the tuple you created in the last line consisting of the lambda and the `list` variable.

Comment: And refrain from using 'list' and 'file' as they're built-ins. (It's legal, but really bad practice.)

Comment: I was looking for lambda way of doing this:
for i in list:
    file.write(str(i) + "\n")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095055/lambda-and-file-writing#comment71363393_42095055), I guess what you're trying to do is:

```
map(lambda i: file.write(str(i) + "\n"), list)
```

However, I think the code you were apparently trying to avoid would be more readable:

```
for i in list:
    file.write(str(i) + "\n")
```

(Also, take [Peter's note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095055/lambda-and-file-writing/42115621#comment71360952_42095055) to heart... using `list` as a variable will come back to haunt you someday when you try to use the `list()` built-in function and find it's been overridden.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm aware of the fact that using naming conventions that are similar or same as built-in ones is a 'buggy' proposition. I was just curious about lambda in this instance, how it works and why it didn't work for me as I slapped it together on a fly. I'm still a noob and get curious about details.